# Why I got 'Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null' when creating buttons dynamically?

Tags: javascript

Why those buttons have null property instead of creating themselves?

Javascript code:

```
let textAlignButtonsDiv = document.getElementById('textAlignButtonsDiv')
const textAlign = ['left', 'center', 'right']

function constructAlignButtons(textAlign) {
    for (let item of textAlign) {
        let button = document.createElement('button');
        button.textContent = item;
        textAlignButtonsDiv.appendChild(button);
    }
}

constructAlignButtons(textAlign);
```

Html code:

```
<div id="textAlignButtonDiv"></div>
```

Comment: It probably means that your JS is executed before your `<div id="textAlignButtonsDiv">` element. Move your script to the bottom of the page before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: `textAlignButtonsDiv !== textAlignButtonDiv` (plural buttons in script vs. singular button in markup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button ID in the HTML is different than the one in your code.

Change it to:

`<div id="textAlignButtonsDiv"></div>`

instead of:

`<div id="textAlignButtonDiv"></div>`

Comment: Vote to close as typo instead of adding it as an answer